# Device confusing internal storage with external storage

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, internal-storage, external-sd, insufficient-memory

Ok! I'm going to try my best to explain this but it will be hard because it's sort of confusing. It's confusing to me in the least so it's hard for me to explain.

---

*Device:* **Proscan PLT1066**

*Andriod Version:* **4.1 Jelly Bean**

---

*A few statements:*

- My device is showing two internal storages but there is only one.
- My device is reading a SD card but I have no SD card mounted in the device.
- When mounting my SD card into the device it reads it but it doesn't?

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

I have two Apps installed.

- ES File Explorer
- Google Play Games

My ES File Explorer shows only one SD card that is named sdcard0.

sdcard0 - 108.15 MB/4.79 GB

---

My Apps in my system settings show:

- Downloaded - Internal Storage - 752 MB used - 130 MB free
- ON SD CARD - SD card storage 108 MB Used - 4.7GB free

---

What I have posted above is all before I mount my 16GB SD card. After I mount my 16GB SD card it doesn't change much. It shows that the SD card is mounted and how much space it has but once I go back into my App settings it still says

- ON SD CARD - SD card storage 108 MB Used - 4.7GB free.

Also when I go into my ES File Explorer it shows the SD card and it is named external_sdcard.

- ES File shows: external_sdcard - 8.00 KB/14.71 GB

It's clearly able to read my SD card. Both the device and ES File Explorer can see the SD card perfectly and can read the amount of space I have on the SD card.

Except I can't use the SD card. When I'm try to install an app I get an error "Insufficient Storage". By the amount of space the device has and the amount of space my SD card has I'm pretty sure I have enough storage space to download just about any game. Yet, it won't let me download anything.

---

I guess to make it simple. There is one internal storage on my device but it's reading two and has mistaken one for the SD card. My device can read that there is a SD card mounted when there is not and when I actually mount one it won't use it.

---

Any help into solving this is greatly appreciated. If you need any more info feel free to ask and I'll answer as fast as I can.

Note: I would provide more images but I'm limited on how many I can post.

Comment: I've had what I think is the same problem with my tablet in KitKat.  I'm watching to see what if anything you get on this.

Comment: Sadly that is the way things are.  People started making phones without any external storage, but apps needed external storage so they split the internal storage and pretended some of it was external.  This then got replicated onto devices with real external storage so the manufacturer could ship the device with no SD card in it.  It's a mess.